# Avoid to cut an equation at the end of a varwidth standalone document

Tags: spacing, equations, cuted

I need something very simple: three equations containing phasors, each one in a different line, aligned at the left. Afterwards, I'm converting to image using Magick Image (magick -density 600 document.pdf image.png). Please see my code at the end, together with the image.

The problem is that the third horizontal line containing the degrees of the phasor gets cutted, and does not appear in the pdf, nor in the image. I have tried to create a blank space at the bottom, but did not work. Any help? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{50in}
\raggedright
{
$\vec{E_{1}}=E \phase{0^{\circ}}$
\\\
$\vec{E_{2}}=E \phase{-120^{\circ}}$
\\\
$\vec{E_{3}}=E \phase{+120^{\circ}}$
}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. When posting an example of code, please put four spaces at the start of every line.

Comment: Thank you very much José Carlos Santos! I did not know how to make that part look as the code... Now I know.

Comment: Adding an extra "\\\" on a new line after the last equation worked for me somehow. Are you sure it doesn't work for you?

Comment: You can also try using $$ instead of $.

Comment: Dear Gregor. Thank you! Second solution, $$ instead of $, avoids cutting last equation, but adds too much extra space between equations. On the other hand, somebody edited my first attempt and wrote \\\ instead of \\ between equations (I did not know that command, new at Latex...). As you mentioned, adding \\\ at the end gives an extra blank line, and the third equation is not cutted. I will use this solution, but still looking for a way to add a small horizontal space, enough to just not cutting the equation. Something like \vspace, which here does not work for some reason. Thank you again!

Comment: BTW, `\\\ ` is actually `\\ ` and  `\space`.  Occasionally the web site does odd things to \\.

Comment: Evidently `\phase` overlaps the text without modifying the depth.  Just add a `\strut` to the end of the last line (SOP with minipages etc.).

Comment: Thank Kormylo! \strut it is exactly what I was looking for! One more thing: the vector arrow on the first equation gets slightly cutted at the top. Do you know how to avoid this cutting?

Comment: @joan - `\rule{0pt}{12pt}` at the beginning seems to do the trick.

Comment: Off-topic ... I'm not really familiar with `varwidth`, but `50in` seems a bit excessive -- it's well over a meter!   Perhaps `5.0in" is intended?